# How to get selected UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift

I have UICollection view with more sections. I want to get the selected custom cell to change the background. I do this with this code:

```
let cell = brandsCollection.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as BrandCollectionCell
```

But when i click on it app crashes with message:
"unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
I add this code in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`

Another problem when I want to loop all cell from section 0 in array

```
for cell in brandsCollection.visibleCells() as [BrandCollectionCell] {

}
```

It gives me that array is empty.

Is there any problem with my `BrandCollectionCell` or something else in swift.
Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: try to search for *"unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value*

Comment: At a guess, your `brandsCollection` property is nil - how are you setting it? Via an IBOutlet?

Comment: Also `cellForItemAtIndexPath` returns a `UICollectionviewCell?` so your code should check that `cell` isn't nil anyway

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use `as?` when casting to your custom cell(s)
2. You should use `if let cell = ???` to unwrap your cells and avoid a crash
3. The returned cell might not be of type `BrandCollectionCell`, that could explain the nil value